# Need to build a FROM clause in T-SQL w/built string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to build the from clause in a query. I need to obtain the database name and append a portion of the name to a cross database query.  (select * from ('x' + database.table))

```
select '[' + LEFT (DB_NAME(), CHARINDEX('-', DB_NAME())) + 'DatabaseName.Table]'
```

The statement above returns the value. I had thought I could use this to populate a dynamic query but it's not working.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @dynamicSql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @sql= 'select '[' + LEFT (DB_NAME(), CHARINDEX('-', DB_NAME())) + 'DatabaseName.Table]''

SET @dynamicSql ='SELECT t.*
FROM
(
   '+@sql+'
) t'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @dynamicSql
```

Comment: What does `it's not working` mean?  Error? Wrong data?...

Comment: FYI, syntax like `'[' + Some value + ']'` is *not* injection safe. If you need to safely quote an object check its validity and use `QUOTENAME`.

Comment: `PRINT(@dynamicSql)` will show you what is wrong...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dynamically construct a qualified table name, fill in the strings directly into the dynamic sql string, i.e. you do not need to use a ( SELECT ...) construct in the from clause.
Something like this:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @dynamicSql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @sql= '[' + LEFT (DB_NAME(), CHARINDEX('-', DB_NAME())) + 'DatabaseName.Table]'
SET @dynamicSql ='SELECT t.*
FROM '+@sql+'
'
print @dynamicSql

/*
Output in database 'Book-Collection':

SELECT t.*
FROM [Book-DatabaseName.Table]
*/
```

Mind that the database name, schema name and table name can each be quoted with square brackets, but putting the whole of the qualified identifier within brackets will make Sql Server read it as a 1 long non-qualified table name.
Also do not forget to put the schema name between the database name and the table name.